# Difficulties with animating div height

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML

```
   <div class="blok1" ></div>
   <div class="blok2"></div>
   <div class="blok3"></div>
```

CSS

```
.blok1 {    
    background-color: green;
    border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;     
}

.blok2 {        
    background-color: blue; 
    border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    position: absolute; 
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}

.blok3 {        
    background-color: purple;   
    border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;    
    position: absolute; 
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".blok1").hover(function(){
        $('.blok1').stop().animate({'height': '400px'}, 100);

      }, function(){
          $('.blok1').stop().animate({'height': '200px'}, 100);      
      });

  $(".blok2").hover(function(){
          $('.blok2').stop().animate({'height': '400px'}, 100);
      }, function(){
          $('.blok2').stop().animate({'height': '200px'}, 100);
      });

  $(".blok3").hover(function(){
        $('.blok3').stop().animate({'height': '400px'}, 100);
  }, function(){
          $('.blok3').stop().animate({'height': '200px'}, 100);
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dtadesigns/2263p/

When hovering the 2nd and 3d div it works like its intended. But when you hover div 1 nmbr 2 and nmbr 3 move a long with number one!

I've been trying a lot of things but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this **CSS**

```
.blok1 {    
background-color: green;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;     
}

.blok2 {        
background-color: blue; 
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
position: absolute; 
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
margin-left: 300px;
}

.blok3 {        
background-color: purple;   
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;    
position: absolute; 
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
margin-left: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make blok1 `position:absolute` and remove `margin-top` from the other two.

http://jsfiddle.net/2263p/1/

Answer (score 1):

In pursuit of the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)est answer, I came up with the following. However, this does involve changing the HTML a bit:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="blok" id="a"></div><div class="blok" id="b"></div><div class="blok" id="c"></div>
    <!-- whitespace removed between bloks on purpose -->
</div>
```

This allows the following CSS, which now uses `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align:top` to achieve your desired result:

```
.wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap; // forces all three bloks onto the same line
}
.blok {
    border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#a {
    background-color: green;
}
#b {
    background-color: blue;
}
#c {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

...and by giving the boxes a common class, you simplify the JavaScript a lot:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".blok").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ // $(this) always refers to the current blok
            'height': '400px'
        }, 100);

    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'height': '200px'
        }, 100);
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2263p/9/

Answer (score 0):

Note 2 things about

```
position:absolute
```

1.
Position:absolute affects the div's position relative to the closest parent of the div which has position:relative

2.When using position:absolute, It's recommended using top,left,right,bottom to position the div. Because absolute elements are out of the content stream.

Programming with the right convention will save you a lot of time.

Here's my solution :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jchnxu/PG69Z/
```